# list index out of range when comparing 2 csv files in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I want to compare and update 2 csv files. If file1 has an extra row more than that of file2, file2 should be updated.

Here's my code:

```
with open(file1, 'r') as f1, open(file2, 'r') as f2:
    old_file = list(csv.DictReader(f1))
    new_file = list(csv.DictReader(f2))
            
    print(len(old_file)) # It is 20
    print(len(new_file)) # It is 23

    for row in range(len(new_file)):
        if len(old_file) < row :
            if new_file[row]['id'] in old_file[row]:
                print(row)
```

This code throws an error in the second `if statement` . If I remove that and print the row info , it works just fine. What's wrong here?

Comment: old_file[20] does not exist, so it errors.

Comment: Yes, but how does it by pass the first `if statement` anyway?

Comment: Because `23 > row >= 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition is the wrong way around.

```
for row in range(len(new_file)):
    if len(old_file) < row :
        if new_file[row]['id'] in old_file[row]:
            print(row)
```

should be

```
for row in range(len(new_file)):
    if row < len(old_file):
        if new_file[row]['id'] in old_file[row]:
            print(row)
```